# Array of strings to float values can correctly sort negative numbers but same values using sprintf, kernel.format, etc. sort incorrectly

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, printf, floating-point-precision

Why can an array of string.to_float values be sorted correctly but those same values are sorted incorrectly when '%.3f' % string.to_float or any variation of that including sprintf, Kernel.format are used?

How can I correct this?

I am currently working on a challenge that gives you a text file which contains lines filled with numbers(Example):

> 1.123 -3.010 3.999 -2.199 -1.212  2.190  4.121 0.000

My goal is to sort these numbers and print them to console exactly as they appear.

My first try at this involved first, splitting these lines into their respective string numbers, then turning them to floating point values with .to_f, and finally, sorting them and joining them back together(space delimited).

This looked something like this:

```
line.chomp.split(" ").map { |e| e.to_f  }.sort!.join(" ")
```

This worked great till I realized that any number such as 68.060 that ended in three decimal places of precision would lose that last zero. and thus show as 68.06 instead of 68.060 which invalidates the solution.

I went around and sure enough found plenty of references on:

```
Kernel.format('%.3f', num)
```

and

```
sprintf '%.3f' % num
```

These were perfect, they solved the issue. I applied them as such(tried variations but they all did the same thing):

```
line.chomp.split(" ").map { |e| sprintf '%.3f', e  }.sort!.join(" ")
```

I then found myself looking at another problem though. Each line that was puts to the console now organized the negative numbers as if they were positive numbers, so instead of:

> -3.010 -2.199 -1.212 0.000 1.123 2.190 3.999 4.121

on console, I was seeing:

> -1.212 -2.199 -3.010 0.000 1.123 2.19 3.999 4.121

This one I could not find much on. This might be my fault for not knowing exactly what to put on google but none of my searches hit anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sorting the array *after* you've formatted it into an array of strings. This means that your array is sorting elements lexicographically, not numerically.

You should first map your array into float values, and then sort it:

```
line.chomp.split(" ").map(&:to_f).sort
```

Now you can format the number appropriately:

```
line.chomp.split(" ").map(&:to_f).sort.map { |e| sprintf '%.3f', e }.join(" ")
```

Comment: I was hoping not to have to use two maps to get it done! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting them after formatting which leads you to sort strings and not float numbers. Just perform the sort first and then map to strings :)